# Retrieving count - LEFT JOIN VS SELECT COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, left-join

I have a situation where I have two possible routes to go down and I was wandering if someone could help me decide which one is better and why. I have tried to look at the execution plan but I cannot tell which one is more performant.

So what I need to do is get the count of each type from one table for every entry in another. In other words what the queries below are attempting to do.

```
SELECT 
    ObjectId, TypeACount, TypeBCount, TypeCCount
FROM 
    Object 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT ObjectId, COUNT(ObjectId) AS TypeACount FROM ObjectAssociatedData WHERE Type = 'TypeA' GROUP BY ObjectId) AS TypeA
ON
    TypeA.ObjectId = Object.ObjectId
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT ObjectId, COUNT(ObjectId) AS TypeBCount FROM ObjectAssociatedData WHERE Type = 'TypeB' GROUP BY ObjectId) AS TypeB
ON
    TypeB.ObjectId = Object.ObjectId    
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT ObjectId, COUNT(ObjectId) AS TypeCCount FROM ObjectAssociatedData WHERE Type = 'TypeC' GROUP BY ObjectId) AS TypeC
ON
    TypeC.ObjectId = Object.ObjectId
```

**OR**

```
SELECT 
    ObjectId, 
    (SELECT COUNT(ObjectId) FROM ObjectAssociatedData WHERE Type = 'TypeA' AND ObjectAssociatedData.ObjectId = Object.ObjectId) AS TypeACount,
    (SELECT COUNT(ObjectId) FROM ObjectAssociatedData WHERE Type = 'TypeB' AND ObjectAssociatedData.ObjectId = Object.ObjectId) AS TypeBCount,
    (SELECT COUNT(ObjectId) FROM ObjectAssociatedData WHERE Type = 'TypeC' AND ObjectAssociatedData.ObjectId = Object.ObjectId) AS TypeCCount
FROM 
    Object
```

Both these two queries gives me the data that I want, albeit the first one gives me NULLs and the second one gives me 0 when there is no associated values, not to concerned about that as I can deal with that? 
My question is more along the lines of which one I should use and why. 
As I mentioned before I have looked execution plan but I am not to sure how to decipher from there which one could be more performant :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither.  You should use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT o.ObjectId, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN oad.Type = 'TypeA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TypeACount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN oad.Type = 'TypeB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TypeBCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN oad.Type = 'TypeC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TypeCCount
FROM Object o LEFT JOIN
     ObjectAssociatedData oad
     ON oad.ObjectId = o.ObjectId
GROUP BY o.ObjectId;
```

If there are types in `ObjectAssociatedData` apart from these three, then you might want to add a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE oad.Type IN ('TypeA', 'TypeB', 'TypeC')
```

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't considered this approach. I am guessing that it is more performant simply on the fact that I am not having to join the same table multiple times. Because I would think that the COUNT WHERE statement would traditionally be more performant than a conditional sum statement.

Comment: @Heinrich , now you are using this query then guess you can use inner instead of left.if there can be only 3 types.

Comment: @KumarHarsh . . . It depends whether or not the OP wants objects with no associations.

Comment: @KumarHarsh, Gordon is correct I do need the objects with no associations so INNER join won't go down well.

Answer (score 1):

I would use conditional aggregation instead.

```
select 
    o.ObjectId
  , TypeACount = count(case when oad.Type='TypeA' then 1 end)
  , TypeBCount = count(case when oad.Type='TypeB' then 1 end)
  , TypeCCount = count(case when oad.Type='TypeA' then 1 end)
from [Object] o
  left join ObjectAssociatedData oad
    on oad.ObjectId = o.ObjectId
group by o.ObjectId
```

or

```
select 
    o.ObjectId
  , TypeACount = sum(case when oad.Type='TypeA' then 1 else 0 end)
  , TypeBCount = sum(case when oad.Type='TypeB' then 1 else 0 end)
  , TypeCCount = sum(case when oad.Type='TypeA' then 1 else 0 end)
from [Object] o
  left join ObjectAssociatedData oad
    on oad.ObjectId = o.ObjectId
group by o.ObjectId
```